# Why isn't the string value updated?

Tags: python

I was writing a for loop that would take a list of strings and add a new line to the end of the string if it doesn't already have one.

My first thought was below, which didn't work:

```
for string in list :
    if not string.endswith('\n'):
         string += '\n'
```

I then came up with below, which did the trick:

```
for string in range(len(ist)):
    if not list[string].endswith('\n'):
        list[string] += '\n'
```

I'm confused as to why only the second one worked - could someone please help explain?

Also, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In the first case, `string` is not assigned back to the `list`. Therefore, when you print the elements in `list`, nothing seems to have changed. In the second case, each element is updated with `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since string is an immutable object, in this code:

```
for string in list :
    if not string.endswith('\n'):
         string += '\n'
```

In every iteration the `string` variable gets assigned an element in `list`, then a new string is created with `'\n'` in the end, but this new string is never being updated back into the list.

Comment: Ah, I see - thanks. Is my second solution the simplest way of achieving this?